# Limit an intStream with a condition

Tags: java, random, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to make an array of random ints like this:

```
static int[] randomInts (int size, int randomNumberOrigin, int randomNumberBound)
{
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current()
            .ints(size, randomNumberOrigin, randomNumberBound)
            .toArray();
}
```

The array would be like this:

> [1, 8, 4, 4, 9, 6, ***0***, 9, 0, 5, 3, 6, ... ]

The task is to limit the stream to the first found zero so that the array would be like this:

> [1, 8, 4, 4, 9, 6, ***0***]

Is there an easy way to make with something like `.limitByPredicate(n -> n == 0)`
?

Comment: Do you have to use the `ints` method?  It would be straight-forward using an ordinary loop.

Comment: Java 9 will have a `Stream.takeWhile`. However, a `stream.takeWhile(i -> i!=0)` will *not* include the zero.

Comment: Yes, I have to use that function.Sorry, if it's a duplicate, but I didn't find the answer here. Maybe you can?